# htaccess + search query

Tags: .htaccess, url, get

So I have my .htaccess ready and working to rewrite my websites link for search query from this:

```
 www.domain.com/search?q=blabla
```

to this:

```
 www.domain.com/blabla
```

It works fine if I type something in my url manualy like shown above, but the problem is once user submits the search it shows as

> search?q=blabla

and it's not a surprise as my form action has search.php, like so

> action="search.php"

*So how do I get proper search submition so it will show only a search word instead of **search?q=blabla** query?*

**ADDED**

My htaccess rules:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What's your htaccess rules?

Comment: What if the user tries to search "search.php"? They would visit `domain.com/search.php`?

Comment: all they need to do is to search in my search form, but I want to make friendly url instead of that ugnly search.php?q=whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /search(?:\.php|)\?q=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

right under `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Perfecto! Thanks for this. I added this together with `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [L]` so it will recognises as an actual search